# Simple URL rewrite does not work

Tags: .htaccess

First, I know there are several questions of this, but what I experience is that other rules work, like removing the .php extension while this rule does not work:

```
RewriteRule ^hello$ marketplace [NC,R=301]
```

This is just a simple test, and it's not working. The URL is still marketplace and not hello. And I have tried to remove all other rules I have and let the rule above be the only existing in my htaccess file, but still, not working.

Any ideas? mod_rewrite is clearly turned on because other rules work.

Tested and not working:

```
RewriteRule ^marketplace$ /hello [NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Highly recommend you to give a read on this "Apache mod_rewrite Introduction"**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,QSA,L]

# Redirect to hello
RewriteRule ^marketplace$ /hello [R=301,NC,L]
# Show the content of marketplace on hello
RewriteRule ^hello$ /marketplace.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

The above is a fully tested and working rule.

First rule will redirect `.php` to directory like URL's for example `domain.com/marketplace.php` becomes `domain.com/marketplace`.

Second rule redirects `marketplace` to `hello`.

Third rule internally redirect `hello` to `marketplace.php` so the URL remains `hello` with the content of `marketplace.php`.

Last rule will verify it directory does not exist but exist as a php file and internally redirect to it.

So if you access `marketplace.php` it goes to `marketplace` then `hello` and from hello you will see the content of `marketplace.php`.

If `marketplace.php` does not exist then you get 404 error.

Comment: I saw that I switched the places, although, it's still not working the other way around. Still no redirect. Look at my edit.

Comment: Nope, the URL is in fact marketplace.php, I have a rule that removes the .php extension and make it to "marketplace" only. Now I just wanna test to change marketplace to hello.

Comment: @JulianAssange and does hello.php exist or do you have the rules to make it internally rewrite to the php?

Comment: Nope, does not exist.

Comment: @JulianAssange then it will result on a 404, as you are redirecting marketplace to a non existent place, unless you have another rule that catches all non-existent URLs to like index.php

Comment: Yeah, I realize that now, but I really just want to rewrite the URL, not redirect it.

Comment: @JulianAssange so you want `marketplace` to go to `hello` and to `hello` to show `marketplace.php`?

Comment: What I want is: typing mydomain.com/marketplace will result the URL to look like mydomain.com/hello, but it's still the markeplace page.

Comment: @JulianAssange then you need 2 rules see my code above the too rules in the middle.